# Cleaning up multiple ForEach and With loops into single action

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, with-statement

I am not getting search results that fit my needs and I think it has something to do with my word usage or terms. I am basically looking for the right wordage to search off of or links to places to find which direction of where to go next. (And not someone to just dump code down, am learning here...).

I am hoping to combine multiple ‘For Each’ and ‘With’ loops into a single action to save on overhead/time to process.

Currently I pull data from a main ‘data dump sheet’ and copy the raw columns that I need to a ‘Column scrub’ sheet.  From the ‘ColScrub’ sheet, then use (at least) three separate ‘For Each’ loops to get the data filtered down to what I need it to be, which has been working well so far though there are sometimes 20+ second delays on the pull/scrub of data and the stuff I have now limits expansion in the future.

The basic rundown is that I am reading from the ‘ColScrub’ sheet, and I have it make a new Temp sheet, and paste some filtered data to Temp1.

After that, I then read from Temp1 and ‘For Each’ again to paste additionally filtered data to a new Temp2 sheet.

Finally, I then read from Temp2 and use another ‘For Each’ loop to further filter and then paste data to Temp3.

Temp3 essentially has the ‘clean data’ I need and from there run other vba or formula from that cleaned data to give presentable data.

A snippet of the code to get from the ‘data dump sheet’ to a populated TempSheet3:

```
Sub CopyRowDataToDiffSheets()
Dim LastRowFromColScrubE As Integer
Dim LastRowFromTemp1 As Integer
Dim LastRowFromTemp2 As Integer
Dim LastRowFromTemp3 As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim c1 As Range
Dim sName1 As String
Dim sName2 As String
Dim sName3 As String
sName1 = "Temp1"
sName2 = "Temp2"
sName3 = "Temp3"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


'''''''''''''''''Copy filter data to TempSheet1
Worksheets.Add().Name = sName1  'make Sheet Temp1
LastRowFromColScrubE = Sheets("ColScrub").Range("E" &     Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1 'count items in col E
For Each c1 In Sheets("ColScrub").Range("E1:E" & LastRowFromColScrubE)  'However many rows are in ColE on ColScrub sheet, set C1 counter as its index
If c1.Value = "In-Progress" Or c1.Value = "Jeopardy" Then  'Add value to index if InProg/Jeo are found in colE
c1.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Temp1").Range("A" & x)  'paste date from ColScrub to Sheet Temp1
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next c1


'''''''''''''''''Copy filter data to TempSheet2
Worksheets.Add().Name = sName2
LastRowFromTemp1 = Sheets("Temp1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1
For Each c1 In Sheets("Temp1").Range("D1:D" & LastRowFromTemp1)
    If c1.Value = "New Connect" Then
        c1.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Temp2").Range("A" & x)
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next c1


'''''''''''''''''Copy filter data to TempSheet3
Worksheets.Add().Name = sName3
LastRowFromTemp2 = Sheets("Temp2").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1
For Each c1 In Sheets("Temp2").Range("F1:F" & LastRowFromTemp2)
    If c1.Value = "New Connect" Or c1.Value = "Change" Then
        c1.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Temp3").Range("A" & x)
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next c1

  '[et el]
```

Ideally, I just want to copy some specific columns (which I can already do onto the ColScrub Sheet) and from that column data to then filter on ColE for only items in 'In Progress' or 'Jeopardy' status, as well as from ColD for only items in 'New Connect' status as well as ColF for items in 'NewConnect' or 'Change' status.

Is there a way I can get the ColE/ColD/ColF filters to all be in one step (and possible add things to filter on like ColAA for a date range and ColAB for text etc)

If that makes sense.

Then i found some stuff on filtering, which is below, but I don't know if I can (or how I can) possible use this filter code to go strait from the original 'data dump sheet' and skip all the ColScrub/Sheet1/Sheet2/Sheet3 creation and manipulation and just filter to the exact column data and conditions I need.

```
Sub test()
Dim CountLV_Rows As Long
Dim wbActive As Excel.Workbook

Set wbActive = ActiveWorkbook
With wbActive
.Sheets("Temp Data").Range("A:T").ClearContents
CountLV_Rows = .Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
.Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows).Copy _
        Destination:=.Sheets("Temp Data").Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows)
With .Sheets("Temp Data")
    .Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows).Sort Key1:=.Range("R1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
                                          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                                          DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
.Activate
MsgBox "Sorted by R"
    .Range("A1", "T" & CountLV_Rows).Sort Key1:=.Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
                                          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                                          DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With
End With
End Sub
```

I got the above to work within my code as it stands today, but don't htink it does anything other than sort by columns

Comment: You will get better responses if you condense your post into a single digestible problem linked to a specific question. That is a lot of code and a lot of explanation for a request that is fairly unclear.

Comment: It is all one problem/issue and the first bit of code is used, is working and is active today.  In the past, I have had 'less words' and gotten responses like 'StackOverflow isn't for newbs' or 'you didn't use ENOUGH words'.   The request is simple and stated multiple times... where can I find better info about combining multiple loops like the ones I've shown above into a single function without needing to make temp sheets.

Comment: I think what mr. Bacon means, is that the problem should definitely contain all the necessary information, but it should also not contain any information that is not necessary. Using "too many" words makes the question hard to read and the problem hard to understand. Be as clear and concise as possible. For example, you ask: `Is there a way I can get the ColE/ColD/ColF filters to all be in one step (and possible add things to filter on like ColAA for a date range and ColAB for text etc)` -- but in relation to your code, it is not clear what the question means (or, what you want to achieve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited**: here follows tested code

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim dataRng As Range

With Sheets("ColScrub")
    .Rows(1).Insert 'temporary "header" row to allow for subsequent Autofilter operations

    Set dataRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion)
    With dataRng
        .Rows(1).value = "temp header" ' assign temporary headers. no matter they actual value, since autofilter will use columns index
        .AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="In Progress", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Jeopardy"
        .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="New Connect"
        .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="New Connect", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Change"

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns("A")) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Temp1").Range("A1")

        .AutoFilter 'remove filters
    End With
    .Rows(1).Delete 'remove temporary "header" row

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @User3598756.  I have been playing with this since you posted this response and am having some issues getting it to run as expected.  I keep getting Run-time error '42' Object Required or Run-time error '1004' Autofilter method of Range class failed depending on how I modify your code example     "Set dataRng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion)" .   Also, in my research, i cannot for the life of me figure out why you have this line "Subtotal(103, .Columns("A")) > 1 Then...", what is the 103 for here?

Comment: I myself "inherited" the "103" magic number from Jeeped to count only not filtered cells in the range specified as the last argument of Subtotal function. I remember I did some searching and found that Subtotal function can be called and act in many different ways on its range argument in relation with the number passed as its first one. And "103" works for the intended purpose. As for your issues you may post the not working files and I'll have a lok at them

Comment: your comment of "act in many different ways on its range argument in relation with the number passed first" triggered something in my brain and I was able to find a useful site this morning (techonthenet) which shows: "The type of subtotal to create, but be careful which method you select. method can be a value ranging from 1 - 11 that includes hidden values or a value ranging from 101 - 111 that ignores hidden values in the calculation." so the 103 means "COUNTA  - Ignores hidden values".  So, at the least, thanks for driving me there... now I am off to the rest of the problem.

Comment: pinned it. as about my answer: if you found it useful you may want to up-vote it. if it fulfilled your original question please mark as accepted. As I posted, I tested it on data as per your question and it worked. cheers

Comment: I did hit the up arrow, but I don't have enough points for it to show up.  The code does filter as you have it, but I am trying to figure out why manual filter versus auto-filter give different results.  The manual filter with drop downs yeilds 777 rows on ColScrub, but the code only shows 170 rows on the Temp1 sheet the data gets copied TO.  I will mark it as complete/accepted once I get past this learning lesson :), will let you know what I find out about why this is happening once I research some more. (And I need to get Temp1 to have the headers from ColScrub, but that shouldn't be a prob)

Comment: As soon as I posted that, I spotted the issue/typo!!!  The autofilter name was missing a "-" accidently, which was cutting out the 600'ish results from Temp1.  I changed "In Progress" to "In-Progress" and everything seems to be working fine now, thank you so much @user3598756 , silly mistake was invisible to me because I was focused on other 'problems' that were not there.

Comment: remember the code does three consecutive filterings, each one acting on the rows subset resulting from the preceding. and precisely it does them in the following order: firstly it select all rows with either "In Progress" or  "Jeopardy" in column "E", then, among the already filtered rows, it select all rows with "New Connect" in column "D" and finally, among the last resulting filtered rows, it select all rows with either "New Connect" or  "Change" in column "F". And, as the "last chance" check for "Temp1" sheet not to have hidden rows....

Comment: I was writing my comment while you already posted yours. so you made it!  fine. cheers